KafkaTemplate.send() is neither returning nor throwing Exception
I'm using SpringKafka (Springboot version 3.1.7) to publish message onto Azure EventHub namespace. Producer application is also deployed in Azure. Everything was working good till last week, but last week all of a sudden application stopped publishing messages. I don't get any error in the console. All I have in the console is the following.
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114622379Z: [INFO]  2024-04-02T20:13:22.114Z  INFO 44 --- [nPool-worker-17] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values: 
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114640679Z: [INFO]      acks = 1
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114646579Z: [INFO]      auto.include.jmx.reporter = true
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114843884Z: [INFO]      batch.size = 16384
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114850884Z: [INFO]      bootstrap.servers = [xxxxxxx-eastus.servicebus.windows.net:9093]
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114855484Z: [INFO]      buffer.memory = 33554432
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114860584Z: [INFO]      client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114864684Z: [INFO]      client.id = producer-1022
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114868784Z: [INFO]      compression.type = none
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114873085Z: [INFO]      connections.max.idle.ms = 180000
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114877185Z: [INFO]      delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114881385Z: [INFO]      enable.idempotence = false
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114885385Z: [INFO]      interceptor.classes = []
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114889585Z: [INFO]      key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114893585Z: [INFO]      linger.ms = 500
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114897585Z: [INFO]      max.block.ms = 60000
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114901485Z: [INFO]      max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114905685Z: [INFO]      max.request.size = 1000000
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114909685Z: [INFO]      metadata.max.age.ms = 180000
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114913586Z: [INFO]      metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114917486Z: [INFO]      metric.reporters = []
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114923886Z: [INFO]      metrics.num.samples = 2
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114940986Z: [INFO]      metrics.recording.level = INFO
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114945486Z: [INFO]      metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114949586Z: [INFO]      partitioner.adaptive.partitioning.enable = true
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114953587Z: [INFO]      partitioner.availability.timeout.ms = 6000
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114957587Z: [INFO]      partitioner.class = null
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114961687Z: [INFO]      partitioner.ignore.keys = false
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114965687Z: [INFO]      receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114969587Z: [INFO]      reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114973687Z: [INFO]      reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114977587Z: [INFO]      request.timeout.ms = 30000
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114981687Z: [INFO]      retries = 3
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114985987Z: [INFO]      retry.backoff.ms = 100
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114989987Z: [INFO]      sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114994087Z: [INFO]      sasl.jaas.config = [hidden]
2024-04-02T20:13:22.114998188Z: [INFO]      sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115002288Z: [INFO]      sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115006388Z: [INFO]      sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115010388Z: [INFO]      sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115014588Z: [INFO]      sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115018688Z: [INFO]      sasl.login.callback.handler.class = class com.xxxxx.config.ProducerAuthCallbackHandler
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115022888Z: [INFO]      sasl.login.class = null
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115026888Z: [INFO]      sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115031088Z: [INFO]      sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115035088Z: [INFO]      sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115039089Z: [INFO]      sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115043189Z: [INFO]      sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115047189Z: [INFO]      sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115051289Z: [INFO]      sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115055389Z: [INFO]      sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115059389Z: [INFO]      sasl.mechanism = OAUTHBEARER
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115063489Z: [INFO]      sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115067489Z: [INFO]      sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115072889Z: [INFO]      sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115077289Z: [INFO]      sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115081390Z: [INFO]      sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115085690Z: [INFO]      sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115098790Z: [INFO]      sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115102990Z: [INFO]      sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115107090Z: [INFO]      sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115110890Z: [INFO]      sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115114990Z: [INFO]      security.protocol = SASL_SSL
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115118790Z: [INFO]      security.providers = null
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115122791Z: [INFO]      send.buffer.bytes = 131072
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115126691Z: [INFO]      socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115147991Z: [INFO]      socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115152191Z: [INFO]      ssl.cipher.suites = null
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115156391Z: [INFO]      ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115160591Z: [INFO]      ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115164792Z: [INFO]      ssl.engine.factory.class = null
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115168992Z: [INFO]      ssl.key.password = null
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115173092Z: [INFO]      ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115177392Z: [INFO]      ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115386197Z: [INFO]      ssl.keystore.key = null
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115423798Z: [INFO]      ssl.keystore.location = null
2024-04-02T20:13:22.115429298Z: [INFO]      ssl.keystore.password = null
2024-04-02T20:13:22.116032312Z: [INFO]      ssl.keystore.type = JKS
2024-04-02T20:13:22.116052813Z: [INFO]      ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
2024-04-02T20:13:22.116058413Z: [INFO]      ssl.provider = null
2024-04-02T20:13:22.116062513Z: [INFO]      ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
2024-04-02T20:13:22.116066813Z: [INFO]      ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
2024-04-02T20:13:22.116070913Z: [INFO]      ssl.truststore.certificates = null
2024-04-02T20:13:22.116075313Z: [INFO]      ssl.truststore.location = null
2024-04-02T20:13:22.116079413Z: [INFO]      ssl.truststore.password = null
2024-04-02T20:13:22.116083413Z: [INFO]      ssl.truststore.type = JKS
2024-04-02T20:13:22.116087713Z: [INFO]      transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
2024-04-02T20:13:22.116091713Z: [INFO]      transactional.id = null
2024-04-02T20:13:22.116095814Z: [INFO]      value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
2024-04-02T20:13:22.116100114Z: [INFO]  
2024-04-02T20:13:22.120245412Z: [INFO]  2024-04-02T20:13:22.120Z  INFO 44 --- [nPool-worker-17] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-1022] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 0 ms.
2024-04-02T20:13:22.120278713Z: [INFO]  2024-04-02T20:13:22.120Z  INFO 44 --- [nPool-worker-17] o.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics    : Metrics scheduler closed
2024-04-02T20:13:22.120307313Z: [INFO]  2024-04-02T20:13:22.120Z  INFO 44 --- [nPool-worker-17] o.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics    : Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
2024-04-02T20:13:22.120332014Z: [INFO]  2024-04-02T20:13:22.120Z  INFO 44 --- [nPool-worker-17] o.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics    : Metrics reporters closed
2024-04-02T20:13:22.120338014Z: [INFO]  2024-04-02T20:13:22.120Z  INFO 44 --- [nPool-worker-17] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : App info kafka.producer for producer-1022 unregistered

Following is the publisher code:
    public void publishOnToInternalTopic(EventMessageType eventMessageType, String message, String logMessage, String internalTopic) {
        
        kafkaTemplate.send(internalTopic, eventMessageType.name(), message)
                .whenComplete((result, ex) -> {

                    if (null == ex) {

                        log.info("### Published {} message");
                    } else {

                        log.error("### Unable to publish message");
                    }

                });

    }

Can anyone please give some solution/suggestions ?
Thanks
Biju
There was no changes done from my end.
Looks like kafkatemplate.send() is neither returning control nor throwing any exception.

If everything was working and all of a sudden it stopped working then you will need to focus on infrastructure. Check all the logs and if nothing of importance there then restart all your applications including Kafka.
This should resolve your problem, if the problem happens after sometime again then a deep dive will be necessary.

When I changed the App Service Plan's SKU it started working again!
